# public property vs static readonly

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to decide among three different implementations.

I have an IPerson interface, all people types (ie. police officer, student, lawyer) implement this. Each person type needs to have a different AddressLocation (ie. home, office, mailing). This location never changes so it can be static/readonly. People are handled generically so my save method SavePerson(IPerson person) takes anything that inherits from the IPerson interface and I have a LoadPerson(int ID) method that takes an ID.

My initial solution was to add a DefaultLocation property to IPerson and only have a getter. This way I can use generic methods to save the data. A problem arises when I try to load the data as I do not have an instance of the class yet so I can not reference the property.

On the other hand I can create a public static readonly DefaultLocation property on each of my people types. In this case I can call Student.DefaultLocation and pass that into the method loading my data.

Which way should I go and why? Both appear to have pros and cons.

A third option came to me as I was typing this question:
What if I used a public static readonly proprty which could be referenced without an instantiation of the class and then used a public property without a setter which could be called from the generic methods?

Per Jon's advice I went with:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    LocationType DefaultLocation { get; }
}

public class PoliceOfficer : IPerson
{
    public static readonly LocationType _DefaultLocationType = LocationType.Office;
    public LocationType { get { return _DefaultLocationType; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last option sounds like the best one to me - at least if you want each type's location to be available to the rest of the code. If you don't, I'd just use a private readonly static field in each type, and return that value from the instance property. (I'm assuming locations are immutable.)

Basically you're using polymorphism here in a *slightly* unusual way in that it doesn't depend on the state of the particular object or any particular behaviour, but the state in terms of the type. Note that by using a property in the interface rather than having an abstract base class with a field set in the constructor, you avoid having one field per instance with basically redundant data.